# Is there any way to create a fixed accelerometer sensor delay on my Android app? I want to achieve, exactly, 20 Hz sampling rate

Tags: java, android

I want to simulate a fixed accelerometer sensor delay with sampling rate 20Hz. (600 samples/ 30sec)

This is for a Human Activity Recognition Android mobile app, that uses TensorFlow to predict the activity of a user. I experimented with fixed `SENSOR_DELAY`(NORMAL, UI, FASTEST) and samplingPeriodUS. I noticed that with the custom value on `samplingPeriodUS` you cannot get a consistent delay, as the sampling rate alters constantly. I ended up, using the `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL` as it gives me a consistent sampling rate, nearly 46Hz.

With this code I collect a 600 accelerometer samples (x,y,z) and then add it to an Arraylist that sends it to Tensorflow to return the probabilities.

With this set I expect to get 600 samples per 13-14 seconds. I want to achieve a 30 seconds delay(20Hz).

Is there any way achieving it with `Thread.Sleep`, `ScheduledExecutorService` or maybe a Linear Interpolation?

The source code's taken from curiousily and has been slightly modified: [Github Link](https://github.com/curiousily/TensorFlow-on-Android-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-with-LSTMs)

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getSensorManager().registerListener(this, getSensorManager().getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    specificActivityPrediction(activity);
    x.add(event.values[0]);
    y.add(event.values[1]);
    z.add(event.values[2]);
}

private void specificActivityPrediction(String activity) {

    if (x.size() == N_SAMPLES && y.size() == N_SAMPLES && z.size() == N_SAMPLES) {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.addAll(x);
        data.addAll(y);
        data.addAll(z);

        results = classifier.predictProbabilities(toFloatArray(data));

        downstairsTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[0], 2)));
        joggingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[1], 2)));
        sittingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[2], 2)));
        standingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[3], 2)));
        upstairsTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[4], 2)));
        walkingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[5], 2)));
        sendProbabilities(activity);
        x.clear();
        y.clear();
        z.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just yesterday I listened to a talk about RxJava. And how you can use Observables, or to be precise: the various **operators** that you get with Observables. It wouldnt surprise me to the least if there is an operator that solves your problem. See here: https://rxmarbles.com/ ... the idea is basically that you have a "stream" of values coming in, and there are these operators to manipulate what and when "things" come in on that stream.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for reminding me RxJava. I'm familiar with the RxJS concepts so i suppose i can figure it out. Rx is great. At first, I"ll experiment with the interval. :)

Comment: Sure. I hope i find one. Thanks